# PHP MVC: htaccess converted to web.config gives me http error 404

Tags: php, web-config, htdocs

I am installed my project done in a PHP MVC framework on a Windows server, but I am having difficulty in making the part of the URLs work.

There are two htaccess, one out of the app and public folders, and one within the public folder.

The first one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I converted to web.config using a tool made available by IIS, and it is working.

But the second htaccess does not work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule  ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Converted:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<!--This directive was not converted because it is not supported by IIS: RewriteBase /.-->
<rules>
<rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^(.+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="/public/index.php?url={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Currently giving error 500, internal server error.

Comment: What is the exact subcode? When you run this code local you'll get a number at the right of the 500 if I'm right

Comment: Have you tried this?

 `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    
</IfModule>`

Comment: @KoenHollander I'm running on an online server, but it doesn't show any sub code.

Comment: @Roshan Yeah, but not worked